# Do adding edges in Neo4j increase the processing required on all queries?

Tags: neo4j, graph-theory, graph-databases, graph-traversal, database-optimization

I am trying to design a database schema for Neo4j. There are several ways to do it. I could put the data as 1) **properties of a node** or 2) **as edges pointing to a node**. The second option is far more powerful in terms of how I could query the data and is preferable given it poses no performance drawbacks.

Will the number of edges slow down queries even if those edges are not involved in the query? I can label those edges so that the engine could ignore them.

Are there any techniques for optimization here?

How much storage do edges vs. properties use?

Comment: Keep in mind that differing edge types (and directions) helps keep down complexity. If you have 100 edges of type A, and 2 edges of type B from a node, a query for only edges of type B will not traverse the type A edges. Similarly, a query for edges of one direction will not traverse edges going the other direction.

Comment: so lets say in your example I had one db with 100 type A, and another DB(same schema) with 1,000,000 type A. Will a query on type B(as you describe) be slower in the second DB?

Comment: No, the number of non-matching relationships won't affect the query. There should be a mapping mechanism in place which only considers relationships of the desired type and direction, and will not be impacted by any number of non-matching relationships.

Comment: that's certainly the sort of answer I'm looking for and I'm thankful for that, except for the word "should". We're not sure this is how Neo4j works?

Comment: I believe there is a change in behavior in how relationships are evaluated from a node depending on the number of relationships. Last I checked that threshold was 50. Below that, an iteration of the relationships will check for type and direction (before expanding). Above that a mapping will be used. You can check this yourself, it's fairly easy to create a node and run a couple queries to add 100k relationships at a time of one time (use `UNWIND range(1,100000) as index` before creating the relationships), then add on a few of another, and query for the few. Low db hits, low execution time.

Answer (score 1):

I'll try answering your questions one by one.

1. Will the number of edges slow down queries even if those edges are not involved in the query?

   Yes, Only if your query has increased number of [cardinality](https://neo4j.com/developer/kb/resetting-query-cardinality/). And using different lables can speed up the search. So make sure you design your schema well.
2. Are there any techniques for optimization here?

   The properties can be indexed but not the properties in relationships. So plan according to your schema. And it is advisable to go with the nodes with properties than relationships. For clear info you can refer to this [blog](https://neo4j.com/developer/guide-data-modeling/)
3. How much storage do edges vs. properties use?

   from neo4j [blog](https://neo4j.com/developer/guide-sizing-and-hardware-calculator/#_disk_storage) we can know the size of the storage each of them occupy.

   Nodes - 14B

   Relationship(edges) - 33B

   Properties - 41B

Hope this helps!

Comment: The query itself will not traverse the edges I'm not interested in. While your answer did expand my knowledge it didn't really address the question directly. If I have edges that will be traversed in the query, can they effect performance in some way?

Comment: Yes. Try labeling them uniquely. Then the performance can be improved.